# Open network location in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to open a file or a folder located on the network? I understand reasons Browsers dont allow that. And I know that I need to add extensions to Chrome and FireFox to get a network folder shown. When I meet these requirements and I have an href that looks like:

```
file://network volume/directory
```

then by clicking on it I get a folder open. Now I need to open it by clicking on a button. Is that even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you jumped all the hoops and completely unsecured your browser (*which I did not, which makes this answer a **guess** rather then a solid answer*), I suppose that javascript actions on `window.location` might work. e.g.

```
window.location.href = 'file://foo/bar/';
```

or the `window.open` API http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

---

A side note, do check the HTML5's file APIs. They explicitely require that user picks the files *explicitely* and do not seem to allow what you require, but they are the endorsed file approach and if, by any chance, your requirements can be met by using them you'll save yourself from a world of pain and going against the flow... See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ for a good starter.

Comment: No, it only works if I physically click on an href pointing to a network folder. The same link will not be opened using window.open(..)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. You want to access a file on the local server.The following would work for you.

```
    window.open("http://www.example.com");//opens a url
    window.open("file://server/serverfolder/index.asp");// server side
```